# OLSR with TDMA base MAC layer

Tags: omnet++, adhoc

Is it possible to use `TDMA` with `OLSR` protocol for `AD-HOC` networks?
I have to work on node scheduling on `Ad-hoc` networks using `TDMA` based `MAC` layer. Is it possible to use `OLSR` for finding the neighbors and `MAC` layer for slot scheduling in `Omnet++`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As they are two completely unrelated protocols on different OSI layers. Yes.

Comment: Thank you Rudi.
I was using olsr for doing node discovery of one hop and two hop neighbors.